# Access AuthenticationState in Blazor Server to update components in a single place

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there a way that I can use in Blazor to check authentication state in one place such as MainLayout.razor, so that when you are navigating to a component I can invalidate state if token expired? For example if you use OnAfterRenderAsync it is too late because the page has already rendered. I do not want to be repeating the check on every component. So I want to know if there is something like a lifecycle function that gets called each time you navigate to a component where I can do something like this

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        if (authState.User.Identity != null && authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            Logout();
        }
        StateHasChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a scoped service for this.

In `Program.cs`

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<IIdentityBroker, IdentityBroker>();
```

`IdentityBroker.cs`

```
public class IdentityBroker : IIdentityBroker
{
    public IdentityBroker(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        this.authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthenticationStateProvider_AuthenticationStateChanged;
    }
    public IdentityInformation IdentityInformation => this.identityInformation;

    public event EventHandler AuthenticationStateChanged;
    private void AuthenticationStateProvider_AuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        var authState = task.Result;
        UpdateIdentityInfo(authState);
        AuthenticationStateChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public async ValueTask<IdentityInformation> GetIdentityInfoAsync()
    {
        if (identityInformation == default)
        {
            var authState = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            UpdateIdentityInfo(authState);
        }
        return identityInformation;
    }

    private void UpdateIdentityInfo(AuthenticationState authState)
    {
        if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = authState.User;

            this.identityInformation = new IdentityInformation
            {
                DisplayName = user.Identity.Name,
                Email = (user.FindFirst("email")?.Value ?? ""),
                Oid = (user.FindFirst("oid")?.Value ?? "")
            };
        }
        else
        {
            this.identityInformation = default;
        }
    }

    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider;
    private IdentityInformation identityInformation = default;

}
```

At the bottom of `MainLayout.razor` :

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    public IIdentityBroker IdentityBroker { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {       
        await IdentityBroker.GetIdentityInfoAsync();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is that the lifecycle methods like OnInitializedAsync is only called once but what I am looking for is something that gets called each time you navigate to a component so that I can be able to check authState and OnAfterRenderAsync is called each time but only after the page has rendered

Comment: @user2857208 This is why I subscribe to ```authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthenticationStateProvider_AuthenticationStateChanged; ```

Comment: @attribute [Authorize] on any page that you navigate to would also check the authentication state

Comment: Can you elaborate on how does your event gets triggered? The @attribute [Authorize] on pages does not trigger get authentication state

Comment: @BrianParker Do you sample code on implementing AuthenticationStateChanged ?